# Prototype and 'this' context confusion

Tags: javascript

So, I am going thru some old saved code snippets and doing a rote "learning" technique on them etc.. Anyways, I came across some code that I don't remember HOW it worked, so I wanted a refresher.

I have two objects and I want to do a mixin (I know there are other ways, and I have those remembered, BUT this one below is the one I need more explanation).

```
var MAN = function() {
   this.name = "MAN."
   this.run = function() {
      console.log("I AM RUNNING", this.name, this.age)
   }
   this.walk = function (){
      console.log("I AM WALKING")
   }
  return this
}

var Billy = function() {
  this.name = "BILLY"
  this.age = 998987
}

MAN.call(Billy.prototype)// <--- THIS is where I'm having issue
var d = new Billy()
console.log(d.run())
```

I understand what is happening in that "call" is setting the "this" context of MAN, to Billy.... BUT, why am I not doing

```
var d = new MAN()...
```

I am setting the context OF **MAN**, NOT of **Billy**... I am seeing "Billy.prototype" here as being borrowed, NOT modified. How is call doing this.. I figured that MAN is being iterated over and the this context of Billy is assigned to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MAN` is a function that **mutates** (changes the properties of) its calling context (the `this` value inside it):

```
var MAN = function() {
   this.name = "MAN."
   this.run = function() {
      console.log("I AM RUNNING", this.name, this.age)
   }
   ...
```

It puts the properties `name`, `run`, and `walk` onto whatever the `this` is inside the function.

When you use `.call`, you call a function with the first argument to `.call` *as the calling context* (the `this` value inside the called function). So

```
MAN.call(Billy.prototype)
```

results in the interpreter running:

```
   Billy.prototype.name = "MAN."
   Billy.prototype.run = function() {
      console.log("I AM RUNNING", this.name, this.age)
   }
   ...
```

Imagine that every instance of `this` inside `MAN` is replaced with `Billy.prototype`.

So, `Billy` now has functions on its prototype, and when an instance of `Billy` is created

```
var d = new Billy()
```

it will have access to the properties and functions on the prototype, like `.run()`.

Comment: Is it a pass by reference of "Billy" into "MAN"... and like you said, the "this" is Billy, and when we "add onto it: this.run", Billy now has a "run".